# WPF Webbrowser control issue when no internet

Tags: wpf, vb.net, internet-explorer, browser, webbrowser-control

I have a Web browser control in my project. Works great! However if I loose connection to the internet then open the project, IE opens and shows the standard cannot display webpage.

I'd prefer the Web browser control in my project show this message and not pop up a IE browser window when the internet connection is lost.

Thanks!

Comment: IE should never be opening in this scenario; the error page should display inside the browser control itself. Without any further information (e.g. your code), it's unlikely that anyone can help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by importing **System.Net.NetworkInformation** namespace. NetworkChange Class exposes a event called **NetworkAvailabilityChanged** which is responsible to notify the application on connection status change. Please find the below snippet. Please mark the answer if useful.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public bool IsAvailable { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged;
    }

    void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        IsAvailable = e.IsAvailable;
    }


    private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsAvailable)
        {
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text);    
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Popup Message");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see IE open on my machine, but I do see the normal IE error messages displaying within the WebBrowser control.

I believe you could detect that the webpage wasn't loaded properly by handling the WebBrowser's `Navigated` event, and looking at the document's url property. Here is some XAML:

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://www.google.com" Navigated="WebBrowser_Navigated" />
```

And a bit of code (I don't do VB, sorry):

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
    var browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    if (browser != null) {
        var doc = browser.Document as HTMLDocument;
        if (doc != null)
            MessageBox.Show(doc.url);
    }
}
```

On my machine, when the navigation failed, I got this URL:

> res:ieframe.dll/navcancl.html#http://www.google.com

While I don't think we could count on the URL being exactly this all the time, I bet you could inspect it and determine that it's NOT the URL you were looking for. In fact, the "http:" is now "res:". When you see this happen (and don't expect it) you could make the browser point to a local source to display a message.

Comment: Use Vimal CK's answer. It's obviously better! lol  +1 to his answer :)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18218796/425871

Comment: Ah I use a nice little translator. C# to VB vice versa :http://converter.telerik.com/